# How to understand the information of my android processor

Tags: android

I'm to meet the speed of my phone and all relavant to the cpu of my phone
So when I run the following command from a shell `cat /proc/cpuinfo` this show it:

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 212.33

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 212.33

Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc05
CPU revision    : 1    
Hardware    : MSM8x25 U8951 BOARD
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

According whit this information isn't a Dual-core ,really?

So, what is the speed ? , what mean all this information?
Thanks!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a dual core procesor. One is serialized no. 0 and one is no. 1.

For interpretation you may refer to https://web.archive.org/web/20131009083823/http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info

Comment: what mean the `cpu architecture:7`

Comment: Here for ARM maybe it is the version of processor but actually it is the type of processor e.g x86 or x64

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're inquiring as to whether or not the output indicates whether or not the cpu of your phone is dual-core or not (or essentially how the output indicates how many cores a given processor does have).  The answer is yes, it's dual-core, as indicated by the lines "processor : 0" and "processor : 1".  The cores are output as separate processors in /proc/cpuinfo.  For instance, the CPU in my desktop is an octocore, and here's the pertinent info from /proc/cpuinfo that indicates such :

*bgestwicki@bgestwicki-desktop:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor

processor   : 0

processor   : 1

processor   : 2

processor   : 3

processor   : 4

processor   : 5

processor   : 6

processor   : 7*

Hope that helps!